# how to append elements in a list in dataframe to elements in a list in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append values of a column in df1 append to values of a column in df2 and the same as for the 'b' column. the result should be:

[image]

Finaly, I have a dataframe that some of its cells have multiple lists:

```
 df1                   a             b
    0 [0,2,3][4,3][7,5,4,3]   [3,4,5,6,7]
```

after printing, it is enclosed in str quotes:

```
'[0,2,3][4,3][7,5,4,3]' '[3,4,5,6,7]'
```

I want to merge the lists in a column into one:

```
[0,2,3,4,3,7,5,4,3]
```

but after running

```
tcs.applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x7fef5aa90610>
```

Comment: Please always provide data as text (not as images).

Comment: what changed to the first part of your question where you really had lists in the cell, now these are obviously no lists, there look like list of lists but actually there are just one string. where do you get/or create this data?

Comment: the problem why it isn't working with `ast.literal_eval` is that each list is not seperated by comma. It isn't a list of lists like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) for this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [[*range(5)]],
    'b' : [[*range(5,10)]]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [[*range(11,14)]],
    'b' : [[*range(22,25)]]
})

result = df1.combine(df2, lambda x, y: x + y)
```

Output `result`:

```
                             a                            b
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13]  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 22, 23, 24]
```

**UPDATE** on the new 2nd part of the question.
I really do not recommend to take that as the solution to your problem. The real problem is, HOW do you get data as a dataframe that looks like that. You really should consider working on that instead of dealing with that kind of string malformed list of lists.

Here is what you could do with regex:
Input with `print(df.to_dict())

```
{'a': {0: '[0,2,3][4,3][7,5,4,3]'}, 'b': {0: '[3,4,5,6,7]'}}
```

and the code:

```py
def change_cell(val):
    pattern = r"(?<=\[)([\d\,?]+)(?=\])"
    s = re.findall(pattern, val)
    return [list(map(int,ls.split(','))) for ls in s]

result = df.applymap(change_cell)
print(result)
print(f"type: {type(result['a'][0])} --> cell_value: {result['a'][0]}")
```

Output:

```
                                   a                  b
0  [[0, 2, 3], [4, 3], [7, 5, 4, 3]]  [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

type: <class 'list'> --> cell_value: [[0, 2, 3], [4, 3], [7, 5, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: can you say me how to do this operation for two rows in one dataframe?

Comment: you mean, join two rows, where each row has a list, to one?

Comment: yes. exactly, for example;  row 0 : [1,2,3,4] , row1:[2,7,4] . after merge: row0:[1,2,3,4,2,7,4]

Comment: choose the column and sum them up, since the elements are lists, the lists get concatenated. `df['a'].sum()`

Comment: Can you guide me about second my question?